# ansible -> ec2_instance_facts.py error: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; after upgrade to python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, aws-api-gateway

after upgrading to python 3.7  from 2.7 
I'm getting this error when using with ansible 2.7.0

```
ansible 2.7.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)]
```

getting this error :

```
2020-05-02 11:54:57,580 p=23305 u=ec2-user |  Saturday 02 May 2020  11:54:57 +0000 (0:00:00.476)       0:01:39.534 **********
2020-05-02 11:54:57,750 p=23305 u=ec2-user |  Using module file /home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_instance_facts.py
2020-05-02 11:54:58,120 p=23305 u=ec2-user |  fatal: [10.0.5.187 -> localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  module_stderr: |-
    /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588420497.6072006-50705771655817/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py:17: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import imp
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588420497.6072006-50705771655817/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py", line 113, in <module>
        _ansiballz_main()
      File "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588420497.6072006-50705771655817/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py", line 105, in _ansiballz_main
        invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
      File "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588420497.6072006-50705771655817/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py", line 48, in invoke_module
        imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/imp.py", line 169, in load_source
        module = _exec(spec, sys.modules[name])
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 630, in _exec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_instance_facts_payload_zmc16g7o/__main__.py", line 555, in <module>
      File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_instance_facts_payload_zmc16g7o/__main__.py", line 551, in main
      File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_instance_facts_payload_zmc16g7o/__main__.py", line 505, in list_ec2_instances
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 449, in build_full_result
        for response in self:
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 255, in __iter__
        response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 332, in _make_request
        return self._method(**current_kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
        return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
        operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
        return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
        return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in _send_request
        request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 116, in create_request
        operation_name=operation_model.name)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
        return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
        return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
        response = handler(**kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
        return self.sign(operation_name, request)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 157, in sign
        auth.add_auth(request)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
        raise NoCredentialsError
    botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
  module_stdout: ''
  msg: |-
    MODULE FAILURE
    See stdout/stderr for the exact error
  rc: 1
```

also notice I'm getting :

```
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Although i have the credentials in .aws dir 
and when i doing ec2 simple API call I'm getting results :

python

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15)
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
>>> ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
>>> ec2_client.describe_instances()
{'Reservations': [{'Groups': [], 'Instances': [{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'ami-b66ed3de', 'InstanceId': 'i-be381945', 'InstanceType': 'm5.large', 'KeyName': 'my_app', 'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 4, 8, 25, 17, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'Monitoring': {'State': 'disabled'}, 'Placement': {'Avail .................
```

**UPDATE:**
after updating ansible to the latest I'm getting this error:

```
2020-05-02 11:54:57,580 p=23305 u=ec2-user |  task path: /home/ec2-user/ansible/ansible_linux/roles/package_deploy/tasks/main.yml:5
2020-05-02 11:54:57,580 p=23305 u=ec2-user |  Saturday 02 May 2020  11:54:57 +0000 (0:00:00.476)       0:01:39.534 **********
2020-05-02 11:54:57,750 p=23305 u=ec2-user |  Using module file /home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_instance_facts.py
2020-05-02 11:54:58,120 p=23305 u=ec2-user |  fatal: [10.0.5.187 -> localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  module_stderr: |-
    /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588420497.6072006-50705771655817/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py:17: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import imp
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588420497.6072006-50705771655817/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py", line 113, in <module>
        _ansiballz_main()
      File "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588420497.6072006-50705771655817/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py", line 105, in _ansiballz_main
        invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
      File "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588420497.6072006-50705771655817/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py", line 48, in invoke_module
        imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/imp.py", line 169, in load_source
        module = _exec(spec, sys.modules[name])
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 630, in _exec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_instance_facts_payload_zmc16g7o/__main__.py", line 555, in <module>
      File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_instance_facts_payload_zmc16g7o/__main__.py", line 551, in main
      File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_instance_facts_payload_zmc16g7o/__main__.py", line 505, in list_ec2_instances
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 449, in build_full_result
        for response in self:
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 255, in __iter__
        response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 332, in _make_request
        return self._method(**current_kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
        return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
        operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
        return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
        return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in _send_request
        request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
      File "/home/ec2-user/app_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 116, in create_request
        operation_name=operation_model.name)
      monitoring: true
```

**####################################################**
**UPDATE THE ANSWER**
i couldn't find it on the entire internet!
Im answering my self and to help whom facing this problem
the thing is that boto3 is searching for the AWS credentials in /etc/boto.cfg 
and not in .aws directory ...
so to find out i had to debug ansible using this link which was very helpful
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.2.2.0-0.2.rc2/lib/ansible/executor/module_common.py#L176-L203
in fact i think it is the most helpful link in ansible ecosystem.!
as this how you have suddenly eyes and can understand what is going on !

Comment: Can you consider upgrading to ansible latest version and see if it fixes your issue ? `pip3 install --upgrade ansible`. There has been a lot going on regarding these cloud modules since version 2.7.0...

Comment: i updated my question please look

Comment: I can't see the final error in your latest edit. Is it the same ? If yes, did you double check the credentials are present on the target server (it it is not localhost)... In such case, I would also try to reinstall ansible from scratch in a virtualenv or upgrade all ansible dependencies (i.e.`pip3 install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy=eager ansible`)

Comment: can it be it is failed on the target host ? it can't find python 3 ?

Comment: `did you double check the credentials are present on the target server` ? :)

Comment: isn't ansible will copy it automatically?

Comment: Why would ansible do that ? What if you want to play the module in parallel on 100 remote hosts each having different credentials already configured ? And subsidiary question: if everything is setup on your local computer to get all the info you need from ec2, why don't you play those tasks on localhost or delegate them to localhost ?

Comment: its local task using local_action